# admob interstitial ads implementation in recyclerview not working?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, admob, interstitial

i'm trying to implement admob interstitial ads into my android app... i'm trying to implement the ads in recyclerview, it's working in onClick one time. not working the onClick listener again to open new item.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Anime> mData ;
RequestOptions option;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Anime> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
    MobileAds.initialize(mContext, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    InterstitialAd.load(mContext,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
            // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
            // an ad is loaded.
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            // Handle the error
            mInterstitialAd = null;
        }
    });

    // Request option for Glide
    option = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view ;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_items,parent,false);
    final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view) ;
    viewHolder.view_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                mInterstitialAd.show((Activity) mContext);
                mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, WebViewActivity.class);
                        view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.clcik));
                        i.putExtra("action_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                        i.putExtra("puzzle_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                        i.putExtra("arcade_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                        i.putExtra("adventure_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                        i.putExtra("sports_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                        i.putExtra("racing_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                        i.putExtra("zombie_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());

                        mContext.startActivity(i);
                        CustomIntent.customType(mContext,"fadein-to-fadeout");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getWebsite_logo()).apply(option).into(holder.img_thumbnail);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView img_thumbnail;
    LinearLayout view_container;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        view_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        img_thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    }
}
```

}

i want to do clean ads implementation as professional. please help me to do it perfectly.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use interstitial ads when the user press back button:

> Ads should not be placed in a way that prevents viewing the app’s core content. Ads should not be placed in a way that interferes with navigating or interacting with the app’s core content and functionality.
> [image: screen]
> Examples of non-compliant implementations include but are not limited to:
>
> Placing an interstitial ad after every user action, including but not limited to clicks, swipes, etc. You should place no more than one interstitial ad after every two user actions within your app. Please note that this requirement also applies when a user clicks the **Back button** within the app.

If you want professional Ads implementation use [Recommended interstitial implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201350?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214)

Comment: it's not an answer. i can't implement that's why posted here. you can help me by editing my code.

Comment: @Litu your code violates AdMob guidelines. AdMob will prevent you from showing ad after back button pressed. You should use recommended way, which needs structural changes to your app, so I can't post a useful code for you

Comment: i just updated my question. can you please help me now?